# Merge specific elements but keep document order using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Given the following document:

```
<doc>
  <a>a</a>
  <b>1</b>
  <b>2</b>
  <b>3</b>
  <c>c</c>
</doc>
```

I want this to be turned into:

```
<doc>
  <a>a</a>
  <b>1,2,3</b>
  <c>c</c>
</doc>
```

What I have so far is (mostly taken from another post here at SO):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="doc">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::b)]"/>
      <b><xsl:apply-templates select="b/text()"/></b>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="b/text()">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">,</xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This creates the following result:

```
<doc><a>a</a><c>c</c><b>1,2,3</b></doc>
```

But I'm struggling to find a solution that keeps the document order intact. Any run of `<b>` elements should be replaced by a single  element containing the text of the original  elements as a comma separated list. The other elements should not be reordered.

Comment: "*Any run of <b> elements*" Could there be more than one?

Comment: No, there is only ever one such run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sibling recursion in a different mode:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::b])]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="merge"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::b]]"/>

    <xsl:template match="b" mode="merge">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="next" select="following-sibling::*[1][self::b]"/>
        <xsl:if test="$next">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$next" mode="merge"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Works like a treat. Once again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/doc">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="a"/>
        <b>
            <xsl:for-each select="b">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:if test="position() !=last()">,</xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </b>
        <xsl:copy-of select="c"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is assuming you know the structure of the incoming XML and can enumerate the elements before `b` and after it separately. Otherwise you'd have to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/doc">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::b or preceding-sibling::b)]"/>
        <b>
            <xsl:for-each select="b">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:if test="position() !=last()">,</xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </b>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::b or following-sibling::b)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The structure of the incoming XML may vary, all elements are optional. But your second solution works equally well as the one given by Martin. And it doesn't use recursion, so I guess it will scale better to really large numbers of `<b>`.

Comment: "*all elements are optional.*" Ahem: the above assumes `b` is mandatory. But you could solve that easily by restricting the template to `doc[b]` and let the identity transform handle the exception..

Comment: I think I will combine your solution and Martin's solution. Something like `<xsl:template match="b[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::b])]"> <b> <xsl:for-each select="../b">...</b> ...` and the empty template to remove the rest of the `<b>` elements.

Comment: That could work too. My own preference is to narrow it down at the `apply-templates` stage whenever possible.

Comment: @Markus, note also if you know there is only one sequence of `b` elements you can simplify the matches to `<xsl:template match="b[1]"> <b> <xsl:for-each select="../b">...</b> ...</xsl:template>` and `<xsl:template match="b[position() > 1]"/>`.